# Pillow won't work with python 3 on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use Pillow to make an app for Mac and Windows computers. I have installed Pillow with `pip install Pillow` and `pip3 install Pillow` (uninstalling not working commands between attempts). This works with no errors, but when I run the code below with Python 3.7.0:

```
import PIL as Pillow
from PIL import Image
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ethan/Desktop/Python Projects/Pillow Test/exe.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PIL as Pillow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

However, in Python 2.7, I get no errors.

There were a lot of posts on the web about a problem like mine, but none of them worked.

Is this my computer's problem (I am using a Mac OS X Yosemite) or did I do something wrong? I can explain in more detail if needed.

Comment: Do you have more than one Python 3.x installed? What does `pip3 --version` say?

Comment: Meanwhile, if `python3` is definitely running your Python 3.7, but `pip3` doesn't seem to be installing into your Python 3.7, use `python3 -m pip` instead of `pip3`, and it will definitely run (and install into) your Python 3.7, not any other Python, which will solve your problem. (But you may still want to diagnose what was going wrong…)

Comment: @abarnert you are a genius! Thank you so much, `python3 -m pip install Pillow` worked! No, I did not have another python 3.x, but after looking around it appears that pip3 was installing into Python 2.7! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You need either:

1. Install PIL in a virtual environment (I'd recommend `virtualenv`)
2. Or, run `pip3 install Pillow` on your Mac.

I would always prefer option 1.

You can do it like this:

```
$ pip3 install virtualenv 
$ cd $YOUR_PROJECT_DIR
$ virtualenv -p /path/to/your/python3/interpreter ./venv
$ source ./venv/bin/activate
$ pip install Pillow
$ python
> import PIL as Pillow
>
$ deactivate
```

Now, every time you need your virtual environment on your project, just do:

```
$ source ./venv/bin/activate
```

Remember two things:

1. Add `./venv` to your `.gitignore` file (if you are using git)
2. Keep an up to date `requirements.txt` file on your project (`pip freeze > requirements.txt`)